# Android MediaPlayer Pause Method

Tags: java, android

I have set up a very simple media player in my Main activity class

```
MediaPlayer BackgroundMusic;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    BackgroundMusic = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pirate_music);
    BackgroundMusic.start();
```

I also have a simple pause method

```
   public void pause() {
    if (BackgroundMusic.isPlaying())
        BackgroundMusic.pause();

}
```

I am having trouble finding a way to call the pause method for the media player in a different class. The class is for a menu with a mute button for the background music using a if method. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For future reference if you can't use static, if you're in a fragment class you can call `((MainActivity)getActivity()).pause()`, otherwise you will need to pass the instance (a `Context`) in the constructor of your new class. Then in your new class you can cast the `Context` back to a `MainActivity` and call `pause()` like mentioned before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make that pause method static

```
public static void pause()
```

and then simply call it from another class by running

```
YourClassName.pause()
```